# Is there a way to get the list size from map<string,List<Sobject>>

Tags: apex, developer

Is there a way to get the list size from a `map<String,List<Sobject>>`. 
I don't want the size of the map which can be evaluated using `map.size()`. 
I am looking for the size of the list in each key in the map.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over the lists independently to get the values that you're looking for.

## All Sizes

```
Integer[] sizes = new Integer[0];
for(Object[] theList: theMap.values()) {
  sizes.add(theList.size());
}
```

## Total Size

```
Integer totalSize = 0;
for(Object[] theList: theMap.values()) {
  totalSize += theList.size();
}
```