# How to get a list Size on a Map key without iteration

Tags: apex, trigger, datetime, debugging

I try to write a trigger that set case status to "Closed" if thereare more than 2 cases created that same day (today) associated with the same contact. The problem is I don't want to use SOQL queries in for loops or nested for loops. I try to do it via map with a list as value, but can't get it working.
I looked into this solution: [Is there a way to get the list size from map<string,List<Sobject>>](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237625/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-list-size-from-mapstring-listsobject), but it gives me another for loop which makes it a nested for loop, which i try to prevent. Here is my code:

```
public without sharing class CaseStatusClosed {
    public static void triggerInjection(List<Case> caseList) {

        Set<Id> caseContactIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id, Contact> contactById = new Map<Id, Contact>();
        //List<Case> caseAddList = new List<Case>();

        Map<Id, List<Case>> caseListByContactId = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();


        for(Case myCase : caseList){
            if(myCase.CreatedDate == Date.Today()){
                caseContactIdSet.add(myCase.ContactId);
                //caseAddList.add(myCase);
                if(!caseListByContactId.containsKey(myCase.ContactId)){
                    caseListByContactId.put(myCase.ContactId, new List<Case>());
                }
                caseListByContactId.get(myCase.ContactId).add(myCase);
            }
        }

        List<Contact> contList = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :caseContactIdSet];
        //Contacts related to cases Id of today

        for(Case myCase : caseList){


            if(caseListByContactId.get(myCase.ContactId) != null && caseListByContactId.get(myCase.ContactId).size() > 2){
                myCase.status = 'Closed';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're asking quite the right question here. Generally speaking, using a collection means that you'll also be using loops.

The code that you have right now looks pretty close to correct. Given that you have a `Map<Id, List<Case>>`, you already seem to know that you can use `.get()` on the map to fetch the stored `List<Case>`, and then call `.size()` to get the size of that list.

If you only have one or two contact Ids that you know you're looking for, you could do without the loop. In general though, a loop is the right tool for this job.

Instead, I suspect the issue with your code is that you're comparing a `Date` with a `DateTime`.

`CreatedDate` (contrary to its name) is actually a value of the `DateTime` type. Comparing a `DateTime` directly to a `Date` as you're doing will not work.

To illustrate, try running this code via anonymous apex

```java
DateTime myDT = DateTime.newInstance(2020, 3, 30);
Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2020, 3, 30);

if(myDT == myDate){
    system.debug('Same day');
}else{
    system.debug('Different day');
}
```

You'll find that the system debug we get is "Different day"

If you make a small change though, it will work. `DateTime` has a method `.date()`, which extracts just the date from the `DateTime`. Since you're now comparing two `Date` instances to each other, it'll work as you expect.

Applied to your own code, change the following line

```java
if(myCase.CreatedDate == Date.Today()){
```

to be this instead

```java
// Note that we are now calling .date() to make sure we're comparing two dates
if(myCase.CreatedDate.date() == Date.Today()){
```

### Some parting advice

Generally speaking, when you find that something "isn't working", that's only the first step in the bug-fixing journey. To be able to fix it, or get help in fixing it, you need to try to figure out what specific part(s) are the issue.

Personally, I tend to apply the following approach

- Visually inspect the code, is there anything obviously wrong with it? (did I misspell something, use the wrong method, etc...)
- Try to verify that specific things work like I think they should

  - This usually means taking a small part of the code, like `caseListByContactId.get(myCase.ContactId).size() > 2`, and writing just enough apex (via anonymous apex) to get a `map<id, list<sobject>>` populated so I can do a `system.debug()`
- After that, I'll start from the known point of failure (Cases that should be getting closed aren't) and work backwards

  - Do we get into that final if statement at all?
  - Are we getting into that final loop at all?
  - Is the query for `contList` returning any rows?
  - etc...
- Look at the execution logs, and add `system.debug()` to your code to see the values of variables, the results of expressions, or whether you're reaching a specific point in your code at all

The better picture you have of what's really going wrong, the easier time you'll have in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Derek, and you were completely right. I am a beginning developer so thanks for all the advises. I stored them in a Word document so i can always have it as a reference. As applying the System.debug method to debug my code, i stumbled upon a mistake in my code. Instead of getting the size from all cases in the database, I was getting the size of my constructor list. So with the help of your adjustment and my own debugging I figured out what went wrong and changed what was needed. Hereby my final code:

```
public  without sharing class CaseStatusClosed {
public static void triggerInjection(List<Case> caseList) {


    Map<Id, Contact> contactById = new Map<Id, Contact>();
    Map<Id, List<Case>> caseListByContactId = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();

    List<Case> caseQueryList = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY];

    for(Case myCase : caseQueryList){
        if(!caseListByContactId.containsKey(myCase.ContactId)){
            caseListByContactId.put(myCase.ContactId, new List<Case>());
        }
        caseListByContactId.get(myCase.ContactId).add(myCase);
    }


    for(Case myCase : caseList){
        System.debug(caseListByContactId.get(myCase.ContactId).size());
        if(caseListByContactId.get(myCase.ContactId) != null 
        && caseListByContactId.get(myCase.ContactId).size() > 2){

            myCase.status = 'Closed';
        }
    }
}
```

}